# onCreateSurface() method has a null Camera object

Tags: java, android, android-camera

While developping a camera application I encountered an error, the first time it runs it works and the error only appears when it runs after the onStop method.

My logic was that the camera object would be started and also an object of the class which would process the preview for the camera then the camera object would be sent to the preview class.

The problem is that when it reaches the setCamera function it appears to work and sets the camera but when it reaches onSurfaceCreated the camera object says it's null.

Here's the onResume method in my Activity:

Activity.java

onResume function

```
if(camera == null){
   camera = Camera.open();
   camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
   camera.startPreview();
  }

 if(preview == null){
  preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera_preview);
  preview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);
  preview.setCamera(camera);
  mainLayout.addView(preview);
}
```

onPause method:

```
if(camera != null) {
   camera.stopPreview();
   camera.release();
   camera = null;
}

if(preview != null){
   mainLayout.removeView(preview);
   preview.setCamera(null);
   preview = null;
 }
```

CameraPreview.java

Constructor

```
CameraPreview(Context context, SurfaceView surfaceView){
    super(context);

    this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
```

The setCamera function:

```
 public void setCamera(Camera temp_camera){
    camera = temp_camera;

    if(camera != null){
        supportPreviewSizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        requestLayout();

        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List<String>  focusMode = params.getSupportedFocusModes();

        params.setJpegQuality(10);
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);

        // If the camera supports auto focus implement it
        if(focusMode.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)){
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            camera.setParameters(params);
        }
    }
}
```

surfaceCreated function:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        if(camera != null){
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStrackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any ideas as of why the camera object becomes null in surfaceCreated?

**EDIT**

I found the real culprit it wasn't a null camera object, it was a null List that was called after. However I found it after I realized that the surfaceCreated was being called twice, each time it closes and opens it gets called one more time thus creating an odd behaviour that I haven't understood why it's happening.

Comment: Where are you calling `surfaceCreated()` in your code? Is the `camera` variable out of scope?

Comment: surfaceCreated() it's called after mainLayout.addView(preview).

Comment: I'm not sure why this was upvoted - I'm not saying this to be mean, rather helpful. You should provide a in your post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can use to simulate / troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Right now, I'm not sure how this post doesn't fall under the category "why isnt this code working?" category. Could you please look at the MVCE link, revise your post and maybe we can help you with the "odd behavior" you're challenged by.